# Meaning of "it pools in a little heart around the meat"

Tags: meaning, literature, context

"When Pop plates it, the liver smells, but the gravy he made to slather on it pools in a little heart around the meat, and I wonder if Pop did that on purpose."

"it pools in a little heart around the meat" - what does it mean?

Comment: The *heart* part refers to the shape of the pool of gravy on the plate.

Answer (score 1):

> The gravy he made to slather on it **pools** in a little heart around the meat.

"The gravy **pools** around the meat" = The gravy collects in a pool around the meat. The word **pools** is a verb.

You are probably distracted by "it". Let me clarify:

> The gravy, which he made in order to slather on it, pools in a little heart around the meat. ("**It**" refers to "**liver**").

This pool of gravy has the shape of a heart.

Comment: It doesn’t say the meat is heart shaped.

Comment: @Laurel - so the gravy is on top of the meat in a kind of flat ribbon that forms a heart?

Comment: It’s pooling on the plate, like a heart shaped puddle with meat in the middle.